# Windows CE 5.0 - 6.0 RDP to Windows server 2012 R2

Tags: rds

I have installed Windows server 2012 RDS license on a new Windows server 2012 R2 machine. We need the ability to RDP in from mobile handhelds (Motorola mc 9090 and mc 9100) running  CE 5.0 and 6.0. When I try and RDP in I get an error message "Internal error has occurred" on the handhelds.

After some research I found that it's due the the server using a SHA2 or 2048-bit certificate. Does anyone know of any workarounds for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Windows CE 5.0 doesn't support modern certificate standards, I highly doubt you're going to get an update from Microsoft to change that. Your only choice if you need those clients to work is to reduce the security on your 2012 R2 machine by giving it a cert that your clients are compatible with.

Answer (score 0):

I found this article here http://www.hjgode.de/wp/2014/03/12/windows-server-2012-rds-and-windows-mobile-connection-error/ followed the instuctions and it worked.